# Problems with Startup after Script runs to Shutdown Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, shell-script, hibernate

I have a simple `.bat` script to shutdown a kiosk style machine in our work

```
shutdown -h -f
```

this hibernates the machine and I have it running each evening as a scheduled job.  However my problem comes when I turn the machine on again.  The first time I press power it starts up and then immediately hibernates again, like it runs the script a second time.

the second time I press power it stays up.

Any suggestions on how I can avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling hibernation, rebooting, and then re-enabling it?  Does it do this EVERY time, or is it intermittent?

Comment: It does it every time, though I'm sure it used to work without doing this, maybe an update made a change.

Comment: Does the script run on an event or it is at a certain time?

Comment: @awright18 Runs at a certain time 8pm every evenign.  I switch it on next morning between 9am - 10am

Comment: check windows event log...might give some clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to schedule the shutdown.exe program itself, rather than the script.

Comment: I'll see if that solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check the task scheduler for any other tasks that may be hibernating your PC before this task even runs and just to be sure check if anyone or anything else is hibernating the PC before the event runs ;)
what I think is that this task is always being missed and it tries to run as soon as it can so it runs right after turning on your PC.
*check the task history and see if it's been running on the scheduled time.